# Why isn't the Spring DispatcherServlet finding my controller method?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, tomcat

Let's say I have the following Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class FooController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = { "Content-Type=text/plain" })
    @ResponseBody
    public String foo(String bar)
    {
        return "Bar is " + bar;
    }
}
```

Here's the associated web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID"
     version="2.5">
  <display-name>Foo</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here's the associated servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <bean id="FooController" class="foo.FooController"/>
</beans>
```

FYI, I'm using version 3.0.5 of Spring Framework. I know this is an old version, but it's a constraint that I have to work under.

So I deploy the WAR file (e.g. FooApp.war) built from the above to Tomcat (version 7.0.67). Everything starts up fine. But when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/FooApp/foo?bar=baz, I get a 404 error in the browser and the following in the Tomcat console:

```
Apr 28, 2016 9:43:33 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod
WARNING: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/foo', method 'GET', parameters map['bar' -> array<String>['baz']]
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong in my configuration that's causing this issue? I'm sure it's something, but I'm having trouble figuring out what it is.

**Edit:** Removed the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, per M. Deinum's comment.

Comment: Can you see mapping being created in your startup logs ? If mapping is created it would surely be mentioned there. Also you are using annotations, so why dont you just add component:scan to your servlet configuration, you wont need to do manual url-handler mapping. This is supported in spring 3

Comment: Remove the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, I removed it, but I'm still getting the issue. I'm guessing that the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` is redundant anyways?

Comment: @VineetKasat Yes, I can see the mapping being created:

`Apr 28, 2016 9:58:15 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/foo] onto handler 'FooController'
Apr 28, 2016 9:58:15 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/foo.*] onto handler 'FooController'
Apr 28, 2016 9:58:15 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/foo/] onto handler 'FooController'`

Comment: No it isn't but it servers a whole different purpose. Also remove the `headers` as you probably aren't requesting text but HTML instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum As I understand it, the `Content-Type` header denotes the content type of the response (the `Accept` header denotes the content type of the request), and I do indeed want plain text from the web service.

Comment: From https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers-- it says that `headers` refers to *The headers of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.*. From this I take it that only requests with `Content-Type` set to `text/plain` will be mapped to this method. If you want to specify what is produced from the endpoint then the `produces` property is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, the `produces` and `consumes` properties aren't available in Spring Framework 3.0.5.

Comment: @M.Deinum It turns out that removing the `headers` property fixed the issue! I'll add an answer about it below. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Deinum @gar It seems that I _was_ mistaken about the `headers` property. The key is that it's used to restrict header values in the _request,_ so I was using the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers in the reverse way from how they should be used. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the example project from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/) and started looking at what was different between it and my test project. I finally narrowed it down to the presence of `headers = { "Content-Type=text/plain" }` in the `@RequestMapping` annotation in my controller method. After removing it, everything works.

Answer (score -1):

Add "context:component-scan base-package="package name" /" to servlet.xml. This will enable auto scanning of your controller.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong in setting up the controller manually. Simply leaving it to Spring Framework's "automagic" doesn't give me any greater insight.

Comment: What are you doing to setup controller manually. See when you define only bean in servlet.xml. Your controller is registered as bean only. Not having controller properties. Ok add "context:annotation-config" in your xml. It will tell spring to take Controller as a request handler bean and then it will register it as a controller.

Comment: After defining "context:annotation-config" in the servlet.xml @Controller annotation will work as it will instruct spring to search for this annotation and register it as a handler. I think this will help you

Comment: As I understand it, `mvc:annotation-driven` essentially does the same thing as `context:annotation-config`, just specified for Spring MVC instead of in general. But maybe the version of Spring Framework I'm using is too old for it.

Comment: I tried replacing `mvc:annotation-driven` with `context:annotation-config` but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Using `context:component-scan` did not fix the issue either.